# Initial React npm start build failed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am creating a new react app, but when I run npm start the first time after npx create-react-app, React fails to compile. I have not touched any files and there are no other packages in the directory I created the app in.

This is the error message I get when I run start:

Error: Child compilation failed:
Module build failed (from C:/Users/Matt/Desktop/react/client/node_modules/babe  l-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: [BABEL] C:\Users\Matt\desktop\react\client\node_modules\webpack\buildin  \global.js: 
Cannot find module './src/data' (While processing: "C:\Users\Mat  t\Desktop\react\client\node_modules\babel-preset-react-app\dependencies.  js$0$9")

I have already tried removing the package-lock.json and node_modules then running a new npm install. This has not worked and I have not found any documentation on this issue. I have created other react apps on this machine with no issues until today. Any idea on how to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bug in the core-js-combat version 3.4.6. This nasty bug is already fixed in version 3.4.7. So you can run `npm install core-js-compat@3.4.7 --save` to force the installation of the new compat version.

Cheers